# Django generic CBV queryset with request.user

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

If I do this:

```
class ActivityListView(ListView):
    template_name = "activities/activities.html"
    queryset = Activity.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

I get:

> 'request' is not defined

... obviously. Then, if I do:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    queryset = Activity.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)

    context = super(ActivityListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context["activities"] = queryset

    return context
```

I get:

> ImproperlyConfigured "ActivityListVew" must define "queryset" or "model",

and I understand it. I wonder which is the best way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ListView (or specifically the MultipleObjectMixin the View uses) wants either a constant queryset definition that you can define via a class attribute (your first try), or a dynamic method to get the data, which is done via the 'get_queryset' method. See the docs for details:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset

Answer (score 5):

You should define the `get_queryset` method instead